# Error in C++ : redefinition of class constructor

Tags: c++

I've encountered these two error when trying to compile..

anyone knows whats wrong ?

Was thinking maybe I #include the wrong header file  ? 
the sample of the codes and error as per following:

Error:

```
Square.cpp:8: error: redefinition of ‘Square::Square(bool, Point*, std::string, int)’
Square.h:21: error: ‘Square::Square(bool, Point*, std::string, int)’ previously defined here
Square.cpp: In member function ‘Point Square::getCoord()’:
Square.cpp:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
Square.cpp: In member function ‘void Square::setCoord(Point*)’:
Square.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
Square.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
```

cpp file

```
#include "Square.h"`
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

Square::Square(bool containsWarpSpace, Point coord[], string shapeName, int vertPoint):ShapeTwoD(shapeName, containsWarpSpace) {

 vertPoint = vertPoint;
 coord[] = coord[];

}

int Square::getVertPoint()
{
    return vertPoint;
}

Point Square::getCoord()
{
    return coord[];
}

void Square::setVertPoint(int verticleP)
{
    vertPoint = verticleP;
}

void Square::setCoord(Point coord[])
{
    coord[] = coord[];
}
```

header:

```
#include "ShapeTwoD.h"

class Square : public ShapeTwoD
{
    private:
        int vertPoint;
        Point coord[];

    public:
        //Accessor
        int getVertPoint();
        Point getCoord();

        //Mutator
        void setVertPoint(int vertP);
        void setCoord(Point coord[]);

        //virtual member
        virtual double computeArea(Point x, Point y);

        Square(bool containsWarpSpace, Point coord[], std::string shapeName = "Square", int vertPoint = 4):ShapeTwoD(shapeName, containsWarpSpace){}

};
```

Comment: In your header, you have an errant `{}` at the end of the constructor definition -- thus defining the function in the header.

Comment: @mah It's not just the `{}`, it's also the initializer list for the base class that needs to go.

Comment: How could the compiler make the message clearer?  It tells you where the function is redefined; it tells you where it was defined.  So it gives you the file name and line number for each of the definitions.  To avoid double definition, you have to remove one of the two definitions.  You also have syntax problems in the constructor in the source file.  And do you know whether the unqualified name refers to a function argument or the class member?  It is better (necessary) to use two different names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining the constructor twice, once in the header and once in the implementation file. In the header, you just need to declare it like this:

```
Square(bool containsWarpSpace,
       Point coord[],
       std::string shapeName = "Square",
       int vertPoint = 4);
```

You also need to fix the handling of `coord`, maybe something like changing `coord` to

```
Point* coord;
```

and use

```
Point* Square::getCoord()
{
    return coord;
}
```

and

```
this->coord = coord;
```

in the constructor and `setCoord()`.

Please note that your way of handling `coord` seems strange and dangerous to me, but without further information about what you are actually trying to do it's hard to give specific advise. Generally, consider using the standard containers over manual memory/array management.

Comment: also looks like coord[] = coord[]; will cause issue, Shouldnt this be coord = coord; ? I mean where ever coord is used , looks like its used in a wrong way

Comment: @srsyogesh perhaps `this->coord = coord;`? Unless C++ compiler technology is smart enough to know when you mean the local variable and when you mean the class variable these days? (I'm not saying it isn't but this would be the first time I've heard of that.)

Comment: @Alien Missed the second question/error, sorry. Updated the answer.

Comment: ah well , even i am not sure how C++ compiler works or the syntax of c++  . But looking at it i am sure what is defined in the post is not the correct way .

Comment: i've try removing the [] in coord but theres another error i nv seen before

`Square.cpp: In member function ‘Point Square::getCoord()’:
Square.cpp:17: error: conversion from ‘Point*’ to non-scalar type ‘Point’ requested
Square.cpp: In member function ‘void Square::setCoord(Point*)’:
Square.cpp:27: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘Point*`

Comment: @Alien It would be better if you tell us what do you want to return either a point array or a particular point object itself. If you want to return array then removing [] is not an option.

Comment: @srsyogesh i would like to return an array

Comment: @DanielFrey thanks for helping.
i've tried using the suggested answer for 2nd error but it doesnt seems to be working


`Square.cpp:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
Square.cpp: In member function ‘void Square::setCoord(Point*)’:
Square.cpp:27: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘Point*’ to`

Comment: @Alien Yeah, I missed another bit. See the updated answer to make it compile but please also consider the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler clearly tells you the problem:
You defined the constructor twice once in header file and once in cpp file.

Also, What exactly do you intend to do with:

```
coord[] = coord[];
```

You should understand each and every statement of code that you write. Think about, What do you intend this statement to do? & then match it to the language grammar that you learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Source File:

```
Square::Square(bool containsWarpSpace, Point coord[],
               string shapeName, int vertPoint)
   :ShapeTwoD(shapeName, containsWarpSpace)
{
    vertPoint = vertPoint;
    coord[] = coord[];
}
```

Header File:

```
Square(bool containsWarpSpace, Point coord[], 
       std::string shapeName = "Square", int vertPoint = 4)
    :ShapeTwoD(shapeName, containsWarpSpace)
{}
```

Looks like two different version of the same function.
The one in the header file calls the base class constructor but does not have any code in the body of the constructor.